# To add id and name for image inside tinymce?

Tags: tinymce

**I am trying to insert id and name for image inside tinymce.**

```
var content=tinyMCE.get('faq_answer').getContent()+"--img tag is given here--";
```

I can add image inside tinymce by giving alt, title but i cant add id and name.

Comment: <img></img> tag is given in "--img tag is given here--". Since i dont konw how to add image tag in stack overflow editor. i can pass src,title,alt but i need to pass id and name. please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add an element at the end of your editors content i would do something like this (this way you do not have to get all the editors content and set it again):

```
var doc = ed.getDoc();

// create a new img element
var img = doc.createElement('img');
img.title = 'title';
img.src = '/images/my_image.gif';
img.id = 'my_id';
img.name = 'imagename';

// add the new img element to the dom
ed.getBody().appendChild(img);
```

Some attributes may vanish (be cleaned up) depending on the configuration of [valid elements.](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aConfiguration/valid_elements) If this configuration is not set a standard rule set will apply. You may extend this rule set using the [extended valid elements](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aConfiguration/extended_valid_elements) option. There is a nice example concerning img elements :)